# jQuery not applying before controls visible

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've recently gone from displaying error messages on an asp.net page in a panel that appears at the top of the page to using JQuery dialog so that the users can't just ignore them, and I'm not 100% I'm using it correctly as when it opens, for a split second, the panel is visible at the top left of the page without any JQuery formatting.

[image: example]

The part of the applicable code is here:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/main.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <%--This script will allow the buttons to be styled with the JQuery UI theme--%>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("input[type=submit]").button();
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,

                buttons: {

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        /*This removes the blue halo around the close button in the dialog*/
        .ui-button:focus {
            outline: none !important;
        }

        /*This overrides the ridiculously large titlebar text in the dialog*/
        .ui-dialog-title {
            font-size: 13px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlTicker" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="ticker">
            <div id="dialog-confirm" class="ticker" title="HEP Portal - Alert">
                <div class="tickercontainer">
                    <div class="tickerleft">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgTickerIcon" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="32px" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="tickerright">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTickerTitle" runat="server" Text="" Font-Underline="True" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTicker" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlTickerDetails" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <div class="tickerdetails">
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDetailsHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"
                            Text="Details"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAlertCode" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        Alert Code:
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTickerAlertCode" runat="server" Text="CODE HERE"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                            </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTickerAlertDetails" runat="server" Text="DETAILS HERE"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

And basically, when I want to show my error message, I'll use some code to fill in the labels and then make pnlTicker visible.

I'm also having this split-second style issue with my Login button when the page first loads, it'll show as a regular button, and then change to the jQuery style one.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong here?  Thanks

Comment: If you don't want it to show prior to the JavaScript running, try setting `display:none;` for the items you want hidden (like the dialog box or login button) in your CSS. The client's browser will see the CSS before it runs the JavaScript and will display the element appropriately. After you perform actions in your JavaScript, use `.show()` to show the elements.

Comment: The accepted answer used the same approach, which worked great.  Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide that panel before showing the popup. Because you don't have anything that tells the browser not to show it, it'll display it.

Add this style:

```
<style>
    #dialog-confirm {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

And in your script, show the panel before calling `dialog`:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm")
          .show() /* Show the panel */
          .dialog({
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,

            buttons: {

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That worked beautifully.. thanks.  I've marked as answer